# How to label the last point in a line chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using the code below to generate the chart below it.  I want to add a label that shows the value of the last data point in the chart.  Thank you.

```
min<-as.Date("2003-01-01")
add_columns_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(Index,MTM))+
  geom_line(col="steelblue", size=1.5)+
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle =- 90, vjust = 0.5),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5)) +
  scale_x_date(limits = c(min, NA), date_breaks = "6 months", expand=c(0,0))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-4,4,0.5))+
  labs(y="Percentage (%)",
       x="",
       title= "Monetary Tightness Measure")+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "black")
```

[image]

Comment: `dput(add_columns_data)` would make it easier for others to work out possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Use geom_text with a subset of the data you are plotting that only includes the last date.`TimeSeries[which.max(TimeSeries[,"Date"]),]` is esentialy subseting the largest date from the data set. See my fake data and plotting code below.

```
Date<-seq(as.Date("2014/09/04"), by = "day", length.out = 50)
Value<-sample(-50:50,50)

TimeSeries<-data.frame(Date,Value)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = TimeSeries,aes(x=Date,y=Value))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_text(data = TimeSeries[which.max(TimeSeries[,"Date"]),],aes(label=Value))
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  The solution appears to be static.  I need the last date label to dynamically update as the time-series moves forward in time.

Comment: It would depend on how you are making the time series move forward. If you can provide some example data and code, I can try to be of more help. I am not sure that I am following exactly what your plot would look like without the text being added.